# Large difference in spacing of TOC between book and article class with tex4ht. How to make them both use same spacing?

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht

Compare this TOC in book class with tex4ht

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC must be in preamble
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{section name}
section data
\subsection{subsection name}
subsection data
\subsubsection{subsubsection name}
subsubsection data
\paragraph{paragraph name}
paragraph data

\end{document}
```

Compiled with

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug  main.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

gives (showing only the TOC)

[image]

Notice the amount of shift to the right.  Now compare with this MWE which is the same but book class

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}    

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % for main TOC must be in preamble
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{book name}
my book
\section{section name}
section data
\subsection{subsection name}
subsection data
\subsubsection{subsubsection name}
subsubsection data
\paragraph{paragraph name}
paragraph data       
\end{document}
```

Compiled using same command gives

[image]

I see two problems:

1. In first example above, the amount of shift to the right is too small, it could be little larger, also the paragraph number which `1.1.1.1` is not shifted to the right of the `subsubsection`
2. In book class, the amount of shift to the right is way too large compared to the article class. It will be better if all classes have same amount of shift in TOC. Notice that in book class the paragraph number is now shifted to the right of the subsubsection, which is the correct way to do it, except the shift is too large.

I just like to have nice looking TOC's, even in HTML and not just in PDF :)

Link to tex4ht bug tracking [entry](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?605).

Any suggestion how to fix the above two issues?

TL 2023

**Update July 27, 2023**

I found another problem with TOC in tex4ht, so documenting them here. If I find more, will add here.

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % must be in preamble
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{first part}
\chapter{book name}
my book
\section{section name}
section data
\subsection{subsection name}
subsection data
\subsubsection{subsubsection name}
subsubsection data
\paragraph{paragraph name}
paragraph data
\end{document}
```

Compiled using lualatex and then using `make4ht -ulm default -a warning  main.tex 'mathjax,htm'` gives these different TOC

[image]

Comment: SE questions and answers aren't issue trackers to which you add a running list of problems.  If you've found a new problem, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that TOC indentation for article class is not set up at all, so you get only some indentation from spaces in the HTML file. You can set the indentation using CSS. For example, this example detects if the current document class provides `\chapter` and sets the indentation accordingly. It also uses only `1em` instead of `2em` for each level, so it is not as pronounced:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ifdefined\chapter
\def\indentstart{1}
\else
\def\indentstart{0}
\fi
\def\calcindent#1{margin-left: \the\numexpr #1+\indentstart\relax em;}
 \Css{.sectionToc,    .likesectionToc    {\calcindent{0}}}
 \Css{.subsectionToc,    .likesubsectionToc    {\calcindent{1}}}
 \Css{.subsubsectionToc, .likesubsubsectionToc {\calcindent{2}}}
 \Css{.paragraphToc, .likeparagraphToc {\calcindent{3}}}
 \Css{.subparagraphToc, .likesubparagraphToc  {\calcindent{4}}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result for book:

[image]

And this for article:

[image]

I will eventually update TeX4ht sources, but probably in few weeks.